# Angular and Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Hello I have a problem with Visual Studio / Angular.

When I try to add an import, Visual Studio can't find the object in my Angular App:

nter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYzFL.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "prelnobol",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: BrowserAnimationsModule in `@angular/platform-browser` package. Check your package.json please.Then import like this `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`. Also sometimes `Vscode` does not detect package changes. While in `app.module.ts`, you can also press the `f1` key and run the `TypeScript: Restart TS server` command. @Massimo

Answer (score 0):

In your screen shot, all the way to the top, you see four imports. The `BrowserAnimationsModule` must be imported there as well.

Put your cursor on the scribbled error and press `[CTRL]+[.]`, the context menu will help you to add it.

Alternatively add the import line to your .ts file manually like so:
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

Comment: Ok I solved with [ctrl]+[.] but I have some compilation problem.